# Sending abstract class with DomainService WCF service to Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, domainservices

I was using a simple WCF service with silverlight but I wanted to validate data with annotations and I didn't want to write a whole new layer in silverlight project. So I decided to switch to using a DomainService, created through generating code in the silverlight project.

Now comes the trouble. I have a parent class and about 10 derived classes. Through WCF, I was able to just use the base class. Now I am trying to use a DomainService with the base class decorated with the KnownType attribute. The problem is now those attributes get replicated in silverlight client and a compilation error is thrown. Anybody know how to use DomainService with inheritance? I want to deliver only the information from the base class.

Comment: So you have attributes that you do not wish to carry up to the client proxies?

Comment: Yes, or learn about best practice for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely follow what your problem is, but [this is a great tutorial](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2009/11/24/ria-poco-domainservice-with-existing-business-applications-in-silverlight.aspx) on how to use Domain Services in Silverlight, and the example includes an abstract base class for all entities, similar to what I think you're doing.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to use Domain Service with my poco objects and use inheritance in those poco when sending them to client. Basically I want set baseclass as return type of one method and send there BaseClas's offspring’s and need from Silverlight to be able to understand those types

Comment: So you want a method like this public BaseClass GetSomeData(); but in that method you want to return ConcreteClass where ConcreteClass : BaseClass?

Comment: If so, I don't think that will work unless your Silverlight app has a definition for ConcreteClass with the correct namespaces so that you can cast the response from GetSomeData() to the correct type.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as Kostkac. Did you find a solution to this issue?